# How to find permutations for String arrays excluding own array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, concatenation, permutation

I have the following bunch of arrays:

```
public class ArrayPermutationExample {
    private static final String PREFIX = "ignore(FAILURE) { build(\"load\", ";
    public static final String ENDING = ")}";
    private static String[] arr_1 = new String[] {
        "111",
        "222",
        "333"};

    private static String[] arr_2 = new String[]{
        "aaa",
        "bbb",
        "ccc"};

    private static String[] arr_3 = new String[] {
        "***",
        "&&&",
        "$$$"};
```

I need to find permutation with other arrays, excluding native array.
The output should look like:

```
111aaa
111bbb
111ccc
111***
111&&&
111$$$

222aaa
222bbb
222ccc
...

333aaa
333bbb
333ccc
...
```

Finally, for all those permutations should be added `prefix` and `ending`:

> `prefix` permutation string `endings`

And at the end we should have something like:

> ignore(FAILURE) { build("load", 111aaa )}

I completely stuck with a solution for this task:

```
private static void processArrays(String[] ... arrays) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String[] array : arrays) {
        String[] currentArray = array;
        for (String line : currentArray) {
            // exclude all lines from current array & make concatenation with every line from others
        }
    }
}
```

***How to solve this issue?***

**UPDATE:**

I want to add that finally, we need to have a distinct list without any dublications. Even following example will be duplicating each other:

```
111aaa***
***111aaa
```

I believe that this task should have a solution with **Java 8** style.

Comment: May I knew the reason for downvoting?

Comment: At first glance your example looks pretty complicated, can you provide a smaller example? Will be easier to read and obtain a good overview of your question.

Comment: @Zabuza I updated question

Comment: It is better now, thanks :) Where is the problem in just using an existing **permutation builder** (there are multiple solutions at SO) and modify it a bit? I think that would also help understanding how this problem can be solved, first take a look at how you would do it in general.

Comment: @Zabuza I wondering to know how to use Java 8 style for solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be a combination since you don't actually care about getting all orderings (other than printing in the order specified by the order of the array parameters), but regardless, here is the code I wrote. I used a stack for storing unfinished arrays. Pushing to the stack each possibility at any given point for every array and pushing to results for any completed array.

```
public static List<String> getCombinations(String prefix, String ending, String[]... arrays) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    Stack<String[]> combinations = new Stack<>();
    combinations.add(new String[arrays.length]);

    while (!combinations.isEmpty()) {
        String[] currentArray = combinations.pop();

        if (currentArray[arrays.length - 1] == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
                if (currentArray[i] == null) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < arrays[i].length; j++) {
                        String[] newArray = currentArray.clone();
                        newArray[i] = arrays[i][j];
                        combinations.add(newArray);
                    }

                    break;
                }

            }
        } else {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(prefix);
            for (String string : currentArray) {
                stringBuilder.append(string);
            }
            stringBuilder.append(ending);
            results.add(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

You would just need to iterate over the returned list to print out all of the strings.

As an added note, this method could be written recursively, but I usually like using a stack instead of using recursion when possible because recursion can be slow sometimes.

Comment: Your `return list` contains duplication. One permutation string is repeated 6 times. We should have distinct results.

Comment: you can get rid of this by using HashSet instead of ArrayList `Set<String> results = new HashSet<>();`. Finally, you will get distinct results without any duplication.

Comment: I have modified my answer, but I didn't use a `HashSet`. Seems a bit hacky to me. I'd rather just have it never generate duplicates in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The way I read it: the first array arr_1 is prepended to the next 3 arrays.
I think the prefix is "ignore(FAILURE) { build("load", " and the ending is "}}"

```
String prefix = "ignore(FAILURE) { build(\"load\", ";
String ending = "}}";
for (String first: arr_1) {
    for (String second: arr_2) {
       System.out.println( prefix + first + second + ending);
    }
    for (String second: arr_3) {
       System.out.println( prefix + first + second + ending);
    }
    for (String second: arr_4) {
       System.out.println( prefix + first + second + ending);
    }
}
```

Comment: Right direction! Even more, after the first array -> the same way should be processed the second array -> after it third array -> and finally the last one.
However, I want to find how to create some smart way for such combinatorics instead of procedural style for each array.